# How do I stub non object function using sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I have a non object function

on getConfig.js

```js
export default function () {
 /** do something **/
  return {
    appConfig: { status: true } 
    }
}
```

and under my main file

```js
import getConfig from './getConfig';

export default function() {
 const { appConfig } = getConfig();
 
 if(appConfig.status) {
   console.log("do the right thing");
   else {
   console.log("do other things")
   }
  }
 }
```

How do I mock the getConfig function using sinon stub or mock methods? or is there any better way to set appConfig.status property to make true or false?

I would like to do the following but its not working

```js
import getConfig from './getConfig';
import main from './main';

test('should status to be true', () => {
  
  sinon.stub(getConfig).callsFake(sinon.fake.returns({status:true});
  expect(main()).toBe('to do the right thing')
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ok I found another alternate solution using just JEST

```js
jest.mock('./getConfig', () => (
 jest.fn()
 .mockReturnValueOnce({ appConfig: { status: true }})
 .mockReturnValueOnce({ appConfig: { status: false }})
))

//The getConfig get replaced with the above mock function
```

So the solution looks like

```js
import main from './main';

jest.mock('./getConfig', () => (
 jest.fn()
 .mockReturnValueOnce({ appConfig: { status: true }})
 .mockReturnValueOnce({ appConfig: { status: false }})
))


test('should status to be true', () => {
  expect(main()).toBe('to do the right thing')
  expect(main()).toBe('to do the other things')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `getConfig` function just returns an object so you should just check the returned value (the object.) You don't need sinon at all. What you need to do is asserting the returned value. You can use [`mocha`](https://mochajs.org/#getting-started) test runner for running the tests and an assertion toolking like node's internal `assert` module for assertion.

"is there any better way to set appConfig.status property to make true or false?" How about adding an argument to the function?

```
// using default values for properties
export default function(status = true) {
  // no need for additional `appConfig` property
  return { status };
}
```

Testing (see the `mocha` manual for setting up the environment):

```
import getConfig from './getConfig';
import assert from 'assert';

describe('getConfig', function() {
    it('should return { status: true } by default', function() {
      const ret = getConfig();
      assert.deepEqual(ret, { status: true });
    });
    it('should return { status: false } by passing `false`', function() {
      const ret = getConfig(false);
      assert.deepEqual(ret, { status: false });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have posted the skeleton of my function on the top, in general the status value get calculated in the getConfig file and based on some logic it returns status true or false. and sometimes the appConfig would not have status value

Comment: You are welcome. It's just a basic example, You can use the same logic for testing your `main` function, return values instead of using the `console.log` function and assert the returned values. You can also use the [`chai`](https://www.chaijs.com/) assertion library.